# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to \infty}{(-3)^{2x+1}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate $\lim_{x\to \infty}{(-3)^{2x+1}}?$

I have two solutions for this problem and both of them look valid to me, even though  one of them is incorrect.

Firstly, I know that $(2x+1)$ is an *odd* number, so the limit will be positive infinity when $x$ takes an even number, and limit will be negative infinity when $x$ takes an odd number. Therefore, the limit does not exist.

On the other hand, if I perform some mathematical operations on the function:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}{(-3)^{2x+1}}=\lim_{x\to \infty}{\bigl((-3)^2\bigr)^x\cdot(-3)}=\lim_{x\to \infty}{9^x\cdot(-3)}=-9^\infty=-\infty$$

Where am I making a mistake on my second attempt?

Comment: Does $x$ go over the integers or the real numbers here?

Comment: There isn't any additional information provided. So, I'm assuming it is real numbers.

Comment: Assuming you mean for $x\in\Bbb Z$ as $x\to\infty$, since $2x+1$ is *odd* as you point out, then $(-3)^{2x+1}<0$ for all positive $x$. If you mean for $x\in\Bbb R$ as $x\to\infty$, then you're almost immediately done since then the argument inside the limit is multivalued.

Comment: $x$ being even or odd doesn't matter- as long as $x$ is an integer, $2x+1$ will always be an odd integer (regardless of the parity of $x$ itself)

Comment: "I know that (2x+1) is an odd number,"  If $x$ is an integer  "so the limit will be positive infinity when x takes an even number"  Uh... no.  If $x$ is even then $2x + 1$ is odd so $(-3)^{odd}$ is a negative value.

Comment: @fleablood. Yes, I'm sorry I got confused over such a simple concept. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: "Where am I making a mistake on my second attempt?"  Why on earth do you assume the error is in the *second* attempt and not the first.  Your error is *completely* in the first.  If $x$ is even then $2x + 1$ is odd and $(-2)^{2x+1}$ is negative.  If $x$ is odd then $2x + 1$ is odd and $(-2)^{2x+1}$ is negative.

Comment: "There isn't any additional information provided. So, I'm assuming it is real numbers. "  Limit doesn't exist for real numbers.  If $2x+1$ is an even integer the value is positive and if $2x+1$ is odd integer it is negative.  If $2x + 1 = \frac nm$ where $m$ is even it is not defined.  It is not defined if $2x  + 1$ is irrational.

Comment: You cannot perform nonsense mathematical manipulations if you have no idea what you are doing. $-3^{2x}$ is most definitely NOT $9^x$ for many real values of x.

Comment: @Matthew Liu Can you please give an example of such x value?

Comment: $x = 1/2$  Why do we even have imaginary numbers if $-1^{1/2} = -1^{2*1/4} = 1^{1/4}$

Comment: Try changing $(-3)$ to $(3e^{\iota \pi})$

Answer (score 3):

A negative number raised to an odd number is *always* negative, so "change between negative and positive" is wrong.

So assuming $x$ goes over the integers, the limit is $-\infty$ as the exponent $2x+1$ is always odd. Yes, $(-3)^x$ alternates between positive and negative, but $(-3)^{2x+1}$ is strictly negative.

If $x$ goes over the reals, then before you can evaluate the limit you have to decide what something like $(-3)^\pi$ means.

Comment: I've edited the question and clarified what I meant by "change between negative and positive". So, can we say that the problem should have stated $x\in Z$ to be solvable?

Comment: @EldarRahimli Yes, I think it really should have done that.